# Disable/Enable selected date range on jQuery datepicker UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

So I have the following demo http://dev.driz.co.uk/week.html that shows a jQuery UI datepicker that has multiple instances for each month of the year.

I've modified it so that the user selects entire weeks and then start and end dates for those weeks are stored on the right hand sidebar with a week number.

What I want to do is disable the dates once the user has selected them so they can see on the calender picker what dates have been selected (and also prevent them from adding the same date range more than once).

However I don't know where to start with this... I've created some enable and disable date functions but don't know how to actually disable the dates using the beforeShowDay method.

For example:

```
var array = ["2013-03-14","2013-03-15","2013-03-16"]

$('.week-picker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

But how would I disable a range of dates? As I only have the start and end dates. And can I call the beforeShowDay AFTER the datepicker is on the page like in my example? AND how can I then re-enable the dates?

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {

    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active');
        }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        defaultDate: '01/01/2014',
        minDate: '01/01/2013',
        maxDate: '01/01/2015',
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: true,
        showWeek: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        numberOfMonths: 12,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;

            addWeek($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)), $.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ), $.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));

            disableDates( $.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ), $.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));

            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });

    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });

    $('.remove').live('click', function(e){

        enableDates($(this).attr('data-startdate'), $(this).attr('data-enddate'));

        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });

});

// adds the week to the sidebar
function addWeek(weekNum, startDate, endDate){

    $('.weeks-chosen').append('<div data-startdate="'+startDate+'" data-enddate="'+endDate+'"><span class="weekNum">Week '+ (weekNum - 1) +'</span> - <span class="startDate">'+startDate+'</span> - <span class="endDate">'+endDate+'</span> | <span class="remove">X Remove</span></div>');

}

// disable the dates on the calendar
function disableDates(startDate, endDate){


}

// enable the dates on the calendar
function enableDates(startDate, endDate){


}
```

**In short there are two questions here... How do I disable dates AFTER the datepicker is added to the page. And second how do I disable a range between two dates, as it looks like the beforeShowDay method expects an array of dates rather than a range.**

Comment: do you want avoid duplicates?

Comment: Yes, but this should be handled by disabling the dates when they are selected anyway right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> But how would I disable a range of dates? As I only have the start and
>   end dates.

One way could be to create an array of dates based on the start and end dates that you have. Use that array in `beforeShowDay` to disable the range.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/FAt66/1/***

*For example, Relevant portions of JS*:

```
var startDate = "2014-06-15", // some start date
    endDate  = "2014-06-21",  // some end date
    dateRange = [];           // array to hold the range

// populate the array
for (var d = new Date(startDate); d <= new Date(endDate); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    dateRange.push($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d));
}

// use this array 
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [dateRange.indexOf(dateString) == -1];
}
```

Now, you could set `startDate` and `endDate` whenever a date is selected. In the example fiddle I linked to above, the start and end dates are set whenever a date is selected in the two top inputs. The data array is populated when date is selected in the second input.

**Note**: The above example is additive, i.e. everytime you select a new range it gets added as disabled dates into the target. If you want to clear the existing disabled range before specifying a new range, then you could do a `destroy` and reattach the datepicker. (And also reset the dateRange array)

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/FAt66/3/***

*Relevant portion of JS*:

```
$("#dt").datepicker("destroy");
$("#dt").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: disableDates
});

var disableDates = function(dt) {
    var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dt);
    return [dateRange.indexOf(dateString) == -1];
}
```

---

Looking at your actual code, all you need is this:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
    endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
    var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;

    addWeek($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)), $.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ), $.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));

    for (var d = new Date(startDate);
        d <= new Date(endDate);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
            dateRange.push($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yyyy', d));
    }

    selectCurrentWeek();
},
beforeShowDay: disableDates,
    ...
```

This will keep adding the newly selected date ranges to the array and will additively keep on disabling. But, be cautioned that you will need an escape route when an already selected week is removed. In that case, you may work with multiple array which can be coalesced into one master array.

Comment: I think I've misunderstood what you're doing. As nearly ALL the dates have become disabled on load and the year is 2020. http://dev.driz.co.uk/week.html

Comment: @Cameron: You don't have to do this on load. See my second example. You can add the `beforeshowday` as an `option` later on.

Comment: I think all dates are getting disabled on your site because you already have a `beforeshowday` function in there.

Comment: Okies fixed that part, but when I choose another week, the previous week chosen becomes unselected... Any ideas why? Updated the code at the link. Thanks.

Comment: In case you want additive disabling, then do not reset the array. I mean remove `dateRange = [];` from your `onSelect` code.

Comment: Perfect! So the only remaining thing, is RE-ENABLING them when I click the remove button. How would I do that? I add the start and end date to the sidebar divs as data attributes... but are these useful in this instance?

Comment: @Cameron: I just added that to my answer :) Maybe instead of just one flat array, you could work with an object array. Name the properties with say week name or start date of that week. Then once you click remove on sidebar selection, you could remove that property from the object array. I would suggest, you break it down to a small reproducible standalone example and post as a new question.

Comment: I've tried to remove a selected date range here: http://dev.driz.co.uk/week.html but doesn't work... any ideas?

Comment: @Cameron: Please give me some time. I will have a look at it in another hour.

Comment: @Cameron: Perfect. This is what I was referring to. I was suggesting using object properties, and you used the data attribute to store the start/end dates to splice the array. Great! Cheers :)

Comment: Quick question! Any ideas why the 1st of Jan 2014 is active and remains active on load?? Thanks

Comment: You have specified that as the `defaultDate`

Comment: Thanks pal. Much appreciated for all your help.

Comment: For most date ranges (unless they're really small), it's probably better to create `startDate` and `endDate` as actual `Date` objects and just have the `beforeShowDay` compare the input parameter to them (`date > startDate && date < endDate`) instead of building an array of potentially hundreds or thousands of strings, converting the input to a date (via `.datepicker`), then back to a string, and then doing a string comparison against the entire array.

Comment: @Abhitalks This works great. But in IE its very slow. I have a range between 01/01/2100 and 12/30/9999. Can you please advise.

Comment: @User: Refer to the [comment by brichins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487115/disable-enable-selected-date-range-on-jquery-datepicker-ui/24488299?noredirect=1#comment55169404_24488299) above.

Comment: @Abhitalks thx for the suggestion. Now this is fine and what I did is `if (dt < startDate || dt > endDate) { return [true];}else {return [false];}` . One thing I would like to understand is it is returning true as array. If I remove the [] brackets it fails. Thx.

Comment: @User: Yes. `datepicker` expects an array of three elements (from `beforeShowDay`) first of which is a boolean. The other elements are for specifying class etc. If you read the documentation it will be immediately clear to you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a requirement to disable a list of dates or like if in any reservation kind of projects where we have to disable some dates throughout the process. So you can use following code,

```
$(function() {
    //This array containes all the disabled array
      datesToBeDisabled = ["2019-03-25", "2019-03-28"];

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          minDate : 0,
          todayHighlight: 1,
          beforeShowDay: function (date) {
              var dateStr = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                  return [datesToBeDisabled.indexOf(dateStr) == -1];
          },

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used all the solutions but not worked but i made change in common jquery.datepick.js

Exisiting _isSelectable constructor function

```
_isSelectable: function(elem, date, onDate, minDate, maxDate) {
        var dateInfo = (typeof onDate === 'boolean' ? {selectable: onDate} :
            (!$.isFunction(onDate) ? {} : onDate.apply(elem, [date, true])));
        //This function is modified by Savata to Block fridays on homepage
        return (dateInfo.selectable !== false) &&
            (!minDate || date.getTime() >= minDate.getTime()) &&
            (!maxDate || date.getTime() <= maxDate.getTime());
    }
```

Changed to

```
_isSelectable: function(elem, date, onDate, minDate, maxDate) {
        var dateInfo = (typeof onDate === 'boolean' ? {selectable: onDate} :
            (!$.isFunction(onDate) ? {} : onDate.apply(elem, [date, true])));
        return (dateInfo.selectable !== false) &&
            (!minDate || date.getTime() >= minDate.getTime()) &&
            (!maxDate || date.getTime() <= maxDate.getTime()) && date.getDay() != 5;
```

/*Added last condition date.getDay() != 5 to block friday
In your case change accordingly
for sunday = 0 to saturday = 6
*/      }