# Disable specific date from datepicker in php

Tags: php, jquery

Hiii..

My concept is an agent wants add date from backend which is from(6/07/2015) to until(20/07/2015) these dates will store in database. if agent want disable 2 days(ex. 12/07/15 and 14/07/2015) then how to show these dates disable in datepicker on fron end. Because these two day agent haven't product. That's why agent wants these two day disable and remaining day 6 to 20 should be enable.

Please any body have any idea please help me.
Thanks!!!

Comment: please share some relevant code so that we can help you in better way.

Comment: You can use `beforeShowDay` for disabling date. Please refer to [Disable date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487115/disable-enable-selected-date-range-on-jquery-datepicker-ui)

Comment: Improve your question format.

Comment: Hey..thanks for reply me but i haven't any idea how to implement this concept. Actually, I m new learner  sorry for bad English.

Comment: Datepicker means jquery UI datepicker or bootstrap datepicker..

Comment: yes..jquery UI datepicker..

Comment: Then please refer my answer(post) & it also has the reference link. if its correct then accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

please refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/JjPrU/334/) link. this is working example with jquery datepicker.

Please see below code.

```
var unavailableDates = ["9-3-2012", "14-3-2012", "15-3-2012"];

function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#iDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date("3-1-2012"),
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap datepicker:**

In the bootstrap  datepicker you can use the method:

[datesDisabled](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled)

String, Array. Default: []

Array of date strings or a single date string formatted in the given date format

for example:

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    datesDisabled: ['07/06/2015', '07/21/2015']
});
```

**JQUERY datepicker UI**

In this use the **beforeShowDay** method

```
var unavailableDates = ["9-5-2011","14-5-2011","15-5-2011"];
function unavailable(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
    return [true,"","Book Now"];
  } else {
    return [false,"","Booked Out"];
  }
}

$('#iDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: unavailable });
```

[refernce for JQUERY datepicker UI](http://tokenposts.blogspot.in/2011/05/jquery-datepicker-disable-specific.html)