# jquery datepicker - dont show dates before today with other checks

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker, and I want to not allow previous dates (as well as only specific dates)

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var day = date.getDay();
        var today = new Date();
        return [
        (
    day > today  -- HOW TO DO THIS LINE
 &&

        day != <?php echo $dateday[0];?>
        && 
        day != <?php echo $dateday[1];?>
        && 
        day != <?php echo $dateday[2];?>
        &&
        day != <?php echo $dateday[3];?>
        && 
        day != <?php echo $dateday[4];?>
        && 
        day != <?php echo $dateday[5];?>
        && 
        day != <?php echo $dateday[6];?>
        ),''];
    }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487115/disable-enable-selected-date-range-on-jquery-datepicker-ui. It will solve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'minDate' option to the dataepicker.

```
var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
  minDate: dateToday
});
```

Code Sample - http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/dAyzq/1/