# Disable all dates after specific date in jQuery datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    maxDate: new Date()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />

<script data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

I have a jquery datepicker where I want the max date to be Sep 29'2017. Right now, it's today's date. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable/Enable selected date range on jQuery datepicker UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487115/disable-enable-selected-date-range-on-jquery-datepicker-ui)

Comment: http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/how-to-disable-dates-in-jquery-datepicker-a-short-guide/

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    maxDate: new Date(2017, 8, 29)  //you can provide any future date here
  });
});
```

example:-

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  maxDate: new Date(2017, 8, 29)
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/5pct45bt/

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  maxDate: new Date(2017, 8, 29)
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

You can also use `+1D` for adding 1day plus `today`.

Hope this will help you.