# datetimepicker input automatically filled with current date and disable days before current date

Tags: javascript, html, input, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

i have a datetimepicker input, i want the input automatically filled with current date, but user still can change the date in the input.

i also want to disable the days before current date.

i've tried to use `var today = new Date(); $('#datetimepicker1').value = today;`, but it didn't work. When i alert the value, it still shows that the date is undefined.

i've also tried to use

```
var today = new Date();
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    defaultDate: today
});
```

but it only show table of dates like this [image]

the desired output is datetimepicker automatically filled with current date and the days before current date is disabled.
also, the datetimepicker input automatically updated with the selected date's value. [image] filled with selected date. the date table shows when the calendar icon clicked.

my html code:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type="date" class="btn isi datetime px-3 py-1" id="datetime" name="date" placeholder="3/22/2022">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" onclick="date()"></span>
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487115/disable-enable-selected-date-range-on-jquery-datepicker-ui might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this
`"minDate": 0,`  to disable the days before current date and  `"setDate": new Date()` automatically filled with current date.

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker(
{
  "minDate": 0,
   onSelect: function() { 
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
        console.log(dateObject);
    } 
});




$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', new Date());


 var obj = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate'); 
 console.log(obj);
```

```html
<!-- load jQuery and jQuery UI -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- load jQuery UI CSS theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- the datepicker input -->
<input type='text' id='datepicker' placeholder='Select date' />
```

Comment: it can disable the days before current date, but it also shows table of dates like i posted in the question. the desired output is the table shows when the calendar icon clicked. also i need to change the text in the input button.

Comment: @chimmytata I have updated my answers. now it should works

Comment: can you tell me how to get the value in script? i've tried $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        }).val();
but it didn't work

Comment: @chimmytata I have updated my answer to get get the value

Comment: @chimmytata mark as answered if the answer is useful upvote will be bonus.

Answer (score 0):

setDate with the current date in will generate a preselected date that is today, minDate 0 disables previous dates. min:current_date also works.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    "setDate": new Date(),
    "autoclose": true,
    "minDate": 0,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$("#tgl").datepicker({
autoclose: true,
todayHighlight: true,
startDate: "dateToday",
format:'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
}):
```

'''

you can add atribute starDate